# Quarkus migration to 2.x: failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed. But works in 1.x

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

We use this configuration for connection to kafka topic:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.topic=trx
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.bootstrap.servers=xxx:9095
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer      
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.ssl.truststore.location=/truststore.jks
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.ssl.truststore.password=${KAFKA_PASS}
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username....
```

it works perfectly fine in 1.x Quarkus versions. But not in quarkus 2.x.

So running quarkus in debug mode consumers are configured differently.

**Quarkus 1.x log**

```
 ... ...
 ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
   ... ...
```

**Quarkus 2.x log:**

```
   ... ...
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
   ... ...
```

The exact error I get is this:
**Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching xxx found.**

It is known that the hostname verification can be bypassed with the ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm parameter to empty value, but quarkus 2 ignore the configuration.

How can I override ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm parameter in quarkus 2.x?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by inserting a dummy variable with the default at least one space:

mp.messaging.incoming.ddd.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=**${MY_VAR: }**

This post was very helpful:
[Provide empty string to Quarkus as the default value for an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70759559/provide-empty-string-to-quarkus-as-the-default-value-for-an-environment-variable)